# append a column based on rowname by referencing a value in R

Tags: r

I have two tables (df1 and df2)

**df1**

```
  | A      | B      | C      | D
  | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
1 | 0.870  | 0.435  | 0.968  | 0.679
2 | 0.456  | 0.259  | 0.906  | 0.467
3 | 0.298  | 0.256  | 0.457  | 0.768
4 | 0.994  | 0.987  | 0.365  | 0.765
```

**df2**

```
  | E      | F      | G      | H
  | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
1 | 0.870  | 0.435  | 0.968  | 0.679
2 | 0.456  | 0.259  | 0.906  | 0.467
3 | 0.298  | 0.256  | 0.457  | 0.768
4 | 0.994  | 0.987  | 0.365  | 0.765
```

and I would like to append which ever of the columns from df2 that appears within a meta data frame I also have to df1. The meta data frame will update as the programme runs (it uses a repeat / break function)

**meta_frame**

```
  | letter |
  | ------ | 
1 | G      |
```

I have this code but putting "s around the value var means it no longer works (i.e. running this with "var" replace with "G" would work)

```
var  = meta_frame$letter
df1 <- cbind(no_time, df2[, "var"] [match(rownames(df1), rownames(df2))])
```

Comment: So you're saying that if the column label appears in `meta_frame`, you want that column from `df2` appended to `df1`?

Comment: Hi, it's more when meta_frame$letter gets populated (with G), I want to append a column called G from df2 to df1 - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the following code would append any columns in `df2` that are listed in `meta_frame` to `df1`.

```
columns.to.append <- unique(meta_frame$letter)
df.new <- cbind(df1, df2[columns.to.append])
```